# Need a two dimensional [string][int] array to store DateTimes

Tags: c#, collections

I can not find anywhere a two dimensional [string][int] array which could assign many `DateTime` for a string.

Example:

```
Array["Branch"].Add(Date);
```

Comment: Could you use a `Dictionary<string,int>` ? Since you want to assign multiple `DateTime` values to one string I would suggest a `Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>>`

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.  If you want to store `DateTime` values, why are you using `string` and `int`?  What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: Tried it, but the string should be the key, int should be the indexer, and the value would be the DateTime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use a dictionary of Lists, like so

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,List<DateTime>>();
```

then you add lists for a string like so:

```
dict["Branch"] = new List<DateTime>();
```

and add dates like so:

```
dict["Branch"].Add(Date);
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thank you all, and sorry for the short details.

Comment: no problem! Glad I could help. Mark it as answered if you can, so it is no longer in the unanswered feed.